# Even Parity Bit

Tags: digital-logic

Why is a '0' added to a BCD code of '0000' to make it an even parity bit? There are no ones in it, and I don't see how adding a 0 makes it even by allowing there to be "an even number of 1's".

Comment: the alternative is adding a one, but then you have an odd number of ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[0 is an even number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero). Therefore, with 0 number of 1's present, "0000" has even parity already. To maintain the parity, the parity bit must be 0. Therefore, the total message will be "0000-0".

Comment: I understand that 0 is an even number. However, the textbook says to make a code even parity, you have to have an even number of 1s. I don't see any ones in the binary code 0000, but yet we are adding a 0 to make the number of 1's an even number...I just dont see that.

Comment: You have to add one bit to create the parity bit.  If you have a 4 bit value with even or odd parity you still need a total of 5 bits to represent the data + parity.  When using even parity, if you already have an even number of 1's, then you add a 0 to maintain that even number.  If you have an odd number of 1's, then you add another 1 to make the total number of 1's even.

Comment: @Dean Franks. Thank you for the clarification. Your explanation made much more sense to me.

Comment: There is also mark parity where the extra bit is always 1 and space parity where it is always 0.

Comment: Clarified my answer a bit. Apologies @DeeTee, I misinterpreted the part of understanding you were lacking, so I've covered both now (0 being even, and also the necessity of always having a parity bit whether it is 0 or 1).

Comment: @DSWG. Yes I saw that and was even more clarified! Thank you for your help. I have accepted your answer.